# Is there a Gradle equivalent to the publishToMavenLocal task of the maven-publish Gradle plugin

Tags: java, maven, gradle, gradle-plugin, maven-publish

I `apply plugin: 'maven-publish'` in my `build.gradle` in order to install artifacts into the local `~/.m2` Maven repository by executing `gradle publishToMavenLocal`.

I have now searched for a while and I found lots of information on how to `publishToMavenLocal`, but none on how to publish into the local `~/.gradle` directory. I tried `publishToGradleLocal`, but the task does not exist. Also, the [plugin code](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/publish/maven/tasks/AbstractPublishToMaven.html) makes me assume that there is support for Gradle repositories, but for Maven repositories, only.

- If such exists, which is the common way to publish directly into the local `~/.gradle` directory?
- If not, I understand that `publishToMavenLocal` makes the artifact available for both Maven and Gradle, which is nice. However, Gradle usually caches its dependencies in `.gradle`, which has - as I assume - advantages over caching in `~/.m2`. It's just a guess, but why else would they not directly cache in `~/.m2` in order to make JARs by default always available to Maven and to save disk space? So the plugin developer chose to not go with Gradle standards. I wonder why. Is there a well-documented, *non-opinion-based* reasen for this?

Comment: why do you need to 'publish' to .gradle ?   can you explain your use-case.   .m2 by def is maven repo  vs .gradle is more local cache for the build tool

Comment: No particular use-case, just out of curiousity